# Asp.net pass jQuery variable to C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have go this code inside my razor view in Asp.Net:

```
@section MyScripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function () {

        var myVariable = this.id;

        @{ 
            var Line1 = "Software";
            var Gruppe2 = Model.Where(x => x.Line1 == "Software").GroupBy(v => v.Line2).ToList();
        }
    });
  </script>
}
```

As you can see, the myVariable receives the id via jQuery from the "button click event".

So lets say that the variable value is "Software".

How can I pass this variable to the c# code inside the jQuery?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.  You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how would that work? I would send the variable via AJAX to my controller and give back a new view? The problem is I don't want to reload the whole view... @SLaks

Comment: You need to use AJAX and get back a JSON value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Ajax call to your click event that does a POST/GET back to your MVC action, something like this:

```
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: myJsonString }
);
```

Your action would only return json (or a partial view, depending on the return type)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult MyAction()
    {

        string result = [some model data]

        var json = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return json;

    }
```

Comment: But then I have to reload my whole site or?

Comment: Ah okay I get it now. I will try it tomorrow and give you feedback if it worked!! Thanks a lot

Comment: No, usually you want to get back a json string and then use jQuery to change your UI.  Like, for example, pass a state ID, get the State Description, and add that to a drop-down client-side.

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.